# How make flexible vertical tags with CSS

Tags: css

What style should I give to the following tags so that all three are placed vertically on top of each other and by changing the height of the browser, the first and third tags remain fixed, but the second tag changes its height?

```
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex1">1</div>
      <div class="flex2">2</div>
      <div class="flex3">3</div>
    </div>
```

Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change $breakpoint and $height according to your sizes and units.
You can also use max-height instead of min-height

```
@media (min-height: $breakpoint) {
   .flex2 {
      height: $height !important;
   }
}
```